не работает flex-wrap и flex-shrink: 0;
Пытаюсь сделать так, чтобы item переносились на другую строку при уменьшении экрана и при этом не уменьшался их размер.
Использовал и flex-shrink:0, и flex wrap
<html lang="ru">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Кофейни Барнаула</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="task71.css">
</head>
<body>
<header><h1>Кофейни Барнаула, которые стоит посетить</h1></header>
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li><a href='#'>Renoir</a></li>
        <li><a href='#'>Base coffee</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
<section>
   <article>
    <h2>Renoir</h2>
    <div class="conteiner">
    <div class="item"><p>Уютная минималистичная кофейня.</p></div>
    <div class="item"><div class="square" id="square"></div>
    </div>
</article>
<article>
    <h2>Base coffee</h2>
    <div class="conteiner">
    <div class="item"><p>Стильная кофейня в центре города.</p></div>
    <div class="item"><div class="square" id="square"></div>
    </div>
</article>
</section>
</body>
</html>

CSS
.square {
height: 500px;
width: 100%;
background-color: #ff0000;
margin: 20px;
}

.item {
    width: 400px;
    flex-shrink: 0;
}

.conteiner {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
    gap: 5vw;
    justify-content: center;
    }


У меня на вашем примере всё работает

Немного подправил код, чтобы было ещё нагляднее. Для проверки открываю через браузер страницу и при помощи f12 пробую изменять размеры до параметров экрана телефона.  Элементы просто уменьшаются

Заработало! Большое спасибо)

@AlexKrass, перенеси в ответ

Видимая область страницы больше ширины устройства, после рендера страница подгоняется масштабированием под экран. Условно это те же 400x500 пикселей, но масштаб другой, чем и объясняется видимое уменьшение.
Для решения этой проблемы используется метатег viewport:
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
